# Create a function that installs multiple packages in R

Tags: r, function, package

I'm trying to create a function that checks if two packages are already installed in R and, if they aren't, it installs them.

I tried it:

```
package <- c("data.table", "dplyr")
if(!package %in% installed.packages()) install.packages(package)
```

But it didn't work. It only works if I tried to install only one package at time (in that case, `package` must be: `package <- "data.table"` or `package <- "dplyr"`.

The goal is to write a script and installing packages are the first thing to do. Also, I'm assuming that the user has no packages installed in he/she R environment. That being said, I cannot use `pacman`package for installing multiple packages.

Can someone help me?

Comment: You can use `pacman::p_load`. This function installs the packages if they don't already exist and then loads them

Comment: Thank you @Sumedh. I just edited my question to make it clear that I cannot use `pacman` or any package to check and install the packages because I need to assume that the user has no packages installed.

Comment: `if(any(xx <- !package %in% rownames(installed.packages()))) {
    install.packages(package[xx])
}` would probably do it.